# Uniqueness Fourier coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

Consider a continuous function $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{C}$. Suppose we can write $$f(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n z^n , \quad z \in S^1$$

where $(a_n)_n \in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$. Is the sequence $(a_n)_n$ unique? I.e. if $(a_n)_n, (b_n)_n \in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$, do we have

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_n z^n = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} b_n z^n \implies a_n = b_n \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I couldn't find a reference online.

Comment: What does the $=$ sign mean in your first displayed equation?

Comment: Caesaro summing implies the result here (there other ways too if we know a trigonometric series is a Fourier series of an integrable function - the localization theorem for example); it is a considerably harder but still true result to prove this for arbitrary (when we do not know that the series is a Fourier series of an integrable function, just a convergent trigonometric series) numbers $a_n, b_n$ assuming convergence everywhere, while the result is still true ae for Fourier series but fails ae for arbitary $a_n,b_n$

Comment: $a_n = \int_0^1 f(e^{2i\pi t}) e^{-2i\pi nt}dt$

Comment: @kimchilover Equality is pointwise for all $z$.